# Facebook C# SDK Get Current User

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I m working on a Facebook App. Not a website.

I am trying to use Facebook C# SDK and trying to get Current User and Query Current User info.
How do i do that?

Also, When i try to use an app it s asking for Adding the app, requesting permission to access data, how do i do that also?

Is there a comprehensive examples of these things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're stuck working with .NET 3.5, this will work:

```
var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(FacebookAccessToken);
var me = facebookClient.Get("me") as JsonObject;
var uid = me["id"];
```

Comment: facebookClient.Get("me"): .Get() function not found

Answer (score 0):

You need the access token. Once you get the access token make a request to `me`

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
dynamic result = fb.Get("me", new [] { fields = "id" });
var userId = result.id;
```

Comment: what s the `fields` where does that come from? i m getting error for that.

Comment: it is passing parameters. rather then using dynamic parameters = new ExpnandoObject(); parameters.fields = new[] { "id" }; I'm using anonymous objects. I updated it to be in Get.

Comment: removing my comment above since you have it fixed.

Comment: @prabir when i use CanvasAuthorize it redirects my page for oauth and comes back to my page. Do i have to do this in every page? is it ok to store the facebook user / access token in session? also how do you handle expiry of access token?

Comment: we don't support CanvasAuthorize in v6, you can find the v6 sample at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-canvas-aspnet-sample

Comment: Wouldn't I run into the same problem, that location isn't in the returned result?